# iOS UIWebView - caching assets in native apap

Tags: ios, uiwebview, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching

I am evaluating a project that was originally targeted to be just a PWA using React and Redux.

The application needs offline support though, and needs a sizable amount of media assets (images and videos) to be available offline.

Since the service worker storage limit is just 50MB, this is not feasible for iOS.

I have toyed with the idea of using a native app wrapper that handles the storage of the media files, with most of the app remaining a Redux/React implementation.

Is there a good way to expose such assets from to the UIWebView from the native app? Or are there other common approaches for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

First off all you should try to cache only that assets which are necessary for your PWA.However still if you want to store large files I would suggest you can go with IndexDB API.

IndexedDB is a low-level API for client-side storage of significant amounts of structured data, including files/blobs. This API uses indexes to enable high-performance searches of this data. While Web Storage is useful for storing smaller amounts of data, it is less useful for storing larger amounts of structured data. IndexedDB provides a solution.

**Why IndexDB?**

When quota exceeds on IndexedDB API, the error calls the transaction's onabort() function with Event as an argument.

When a browser requests user a permission for extending storage size, all browsers call this function only when the user doesn't allow it, otherwise, continue the transaction.

If you want know about other possible DB I would suggest you to go through this link
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/